# Nautilus uses all my CPU memory

Tags: 11.10, unity, nautilus

nautilus is using ALL MY CPU in Ubuntu 11.10!!!!
please help, i'm extremely mad and i can't use this distro.

i use a intel core i7 processor. everything worked fine the first 10 or 15 hrs after installing. i reinstalled it one time because of this and now it reappeared. i'm mad as hell, i can't use nautilus at all, it responses with a 5-10 seconds of delay.

[image]
[image]
HELP!

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: As the question is closed, and I can't add answer. Here is the fix I am using & have also suggested on bug tracker : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1069843/comments/35

Answer (score 1):

same problem here
seem to be fixed by removing appmenu-gtk

```
  sudo apt-get remove appmenu-gtk
```